# How to correctly install Avro C?

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, avro

I'm trying to install Bottled Water on Ubuntu 16.04. I installed most of the required packages according to the README file, but I don't know how to build from source Avro C.

I downloaded it from the official web site, and I have searched for instructions on the Internet, also checked the README file. But honestly I can't find a "simple" way to make the build. Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Download the avro source

```
cd avro/lang/c
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ../
make
sudo make install
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi:  I am having troubles also.   I have followed the above instructions.  They appear to work.

When I try to make the quickstop example I get:

```
[root@schma01-rhvm02 examples]# make
[ 50%] Linking C executable quickstop
/bin/ld: cannot find -lavro-static
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [quickstop] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/quickstop.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I appear to have a build/src/CmakeFiles/avro-static.dir but I'm not sure what to do with it.

Thanks,
Mary

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please use answer section only for actual answering. If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context.